# What edits to my code should I make to handle the error?

Tags: java, function, boolean, digits

I wrote a program where function `isHappy` takes in a long value and returns a statement of either True or False based on what the output number is... (1 means True; 4 means false).

The way my program reaches the output is by **squaring each digit of the input `n` and adding them repeatedly until the output is only 1 digit**

For instance, if `n` = 19, the code would return 1 because:

1^2 + 9^2 = 82, from which digits 8 and 2 would do: 8^2 + 2^2 = 68, from which digits 6^2 + 8^2 = 100, from which 1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1. <== 1 is only one digit, therefore, it shall be the answer.

**Please note that every input I get will end up with either 1 or 4**

Anyways, here is my code so far,

```
public class Happy
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            System.out.println(isHappy(989));
        }
        public static boolean isHappy(long n) {
            long sum = 0;
            boolean l = true;
            boolean j = false;
            while (n != 0) {
                sum = sum + ((n % 10) * (n % 10));
                n = n / 10;
            }
            if (sum == 1) {
                return l;
            } else {
                return j;
            }

        }

        }
```

When my plug in test case inputs like isHappy(100), isHappy(111), isHappy(1234), the program seems to work where
**1 = True, 4 means false**

```
isHappy(100) == true
isHappy(111) == false
isHappy(1234) == false
```

However, when I plug in specific numbers like isHappy(989), the program should be true since
9^2 + 8^2 + 9^2 = 226; 2^2 + 2^2 + 6^2 = 44; 4^2 + 4^2 = 32; 3^2 + 2^2 = 13; 1^2 + 3^2 = 10 and lastly 1^2 + 0^2 = 1; which is True.

However, after running my code, my output prints false instead.

I've tried debugging my code but I can't seem to find a problem. Any help on what changes to my code do I have to make would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the two parts of the algorithm: calculating the *sum of squared digits* and verifying if the number is a *"happy number"*.

After calculating the *sum* for the given number in case when the *sum* is naughtier `1`, no `4`, the *sum* becomes a new number to check, and we need to continue with calculating its sum.

So basically we need two loops, or two separate methods.

That that's how it can be implemented.

```
public static boolean isHappy(long n) {
    
    while (n != 1 && n != 4) { // given number is naughtier `1`, no `4`
        n = getHappySum(n);    // calculating the sum
    }
    return n == 1;
}

public static int getHappySum(long n) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        sum += Math.pow(n % 10, 2);
        n /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isHappy(100));
    System.out.println(isHappy(111));
    System.out.println(isHappy(1234));
}
```

*Output:*

```
true
false
false
```